# Is there any newtype for "Either String"?

Tags: haskell

`forall m. MonadFail m => m` can be replaced by `Either String`, by substituting `pure = Right` and `fail = Left`. However, since a `MonadFail` instance for `Either String` is not coming any time soon ([discussion](https://gitlab.haskell.org/ghc/ghc/issues/12160)), I think I'll use a newtype of `Either String` if I wanted to combine `MonadFail` with `Either`.

That said, I believe there are a lot of people who already came up with the same idea. Is there any package that already defines such a newtype? I tried Googling but had no luck.

(use case: using [`iso8601ParseM`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/time-1.9.3/docs/Data-Time-Format-ISO8601.html#v:iso8601ParseM) in a pure code, namely in (a newtype of) `Either`.)

Comment: For a given monad, `MonadFail m` is a *constraint*, not a type. `MonadFail` is a typeclass (kind `(Type -> Type) -> Constraint`), not a type constructor like `Either String` (kind `Type -> Type`).

Comment: @chepner I know, that's why I included `forall m.` in the question. But I think I should have written `forall m. MonadFail m => m` instead. Anyway, I believe you understand my intent.

Comment: So, you could pattern match on the `Either String a` value to decide whether to call `pure` or `fail`, but those are *functions*, not data constructors. There's nothing similar you can do with an arbitrary value of type `MonadFail m => m a` to decide whether to produce a `Right` or `Left` value, ignoring the fact that you can't simply pull a value of type `a` out of the `m a` value in the first place.

Comment: @chepner if `MonadFail (Either String)` had existed, the functions could have been replaced with the data constructors. That is the whole point of this. And if you don't mind introducing language extentions (and orphan instances), it is actually possible. Just let `m a` be inferred as `Either String a` and we can pattern match on it.

Comment: I am just refuting your conjecture that `MonadFail m => m a` is isomorphic to `Either String a`.

Comment: @chepner I said "isomorphic" because it was in my mind that `foo :: Either String a` can be implemented by `bar :: MonadFail m => m a` and vice versa. But it's not always the case e.g. `foo2 :: Either String a -> Either String a` can't be implemented by `bar2 :: MonadFail m => m a -> m a`, so it's actually a one-way transformation! I corrected the question to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very good question in my opinion. So much so that I decided to write a library [`FailT`](https://github.com/lehins/FailT) that solves this precise problem. Here is how it can be used to answer this question:

```hs
λ> import Data.Time (UTCTime)
λ> import Data.Time.Format.ISO8601 (iso8601ParseM)
λ> import Control.Monad.Trans.Fail.String (runFail)
λ> runFail $ iso8601ParseM "2023-01-16T22:14:00Z" :: Either String UTCTime
Right 2023-01-16 22:14:00 UTC
λ> runFail $ iso8601ParseM "2023-01-16" :: Either String UTCTime
Left "no parse of \"2023-01-16\""
```

Here is a blog post [Fail with class](https://alexey.kuleshevi.ch/blog/2023/01/16/fail-with-class/) that goes into much detail about the purpose and other features of the [`FailT`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/FailT) library. In fact that blog post mentions and links to this particular question as one of the motivating examples.